# Python kwargs taking value from other args

Tags: python, function, default, keyword-argument

I would like to make a function that derives 'default' values for kwargs based on the non-kwargs that are passed to it. For example:

```
numbers= [1,2,3,4,5]

def someMath(lst, divideBy = len(lst)):
    return sum(lst)/divideBy
```

In this example, I'd like the default return value of the function to be the sum of the passed numbers list divided by the length of the list.

```
someMath(numbers) # returns 3
```

However I still want the option to change what the divideBy value is:

```
someMath(numbers, divideBy=5) # returns 5
```

Is this possible and how?

Comment: yep definitely a duplicate

Comment: "Dynamic default arguments in python functions" answers my question exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way Python programmers would usually write this is to do the following:

```
def someMath(lst, divideBy=None):
    if divideBy is None:
        return sum(lst)/len(lst)
    return sum(lst)/divideBy
```

Comment: thanks this makes sense - my actual program has a few more args to work with so I'm wondering if it possible to do without writing an ```if not kwarg:``` for each... but maybe it's just not

Comment: Well, off the top of my head you could do something more complicated using `filter(bool...` and the string values of your arguments, but that would be way less readable than simply testing one-by-one whether the values have been supplied or not.

Comment: yea no you are right there's no need.  Your answer is the right answer. will mark as soon as it lets me